# AUCTeX: 'reftex-cleveref-cref' inserts '\eqref' instead of '\cref' for equations

Tags: latex, auctex, reftex-mode

When I run 'reftex-cleveref-cref', which is supposed to insert a '\cref' command in my LaTeX file, I get the expected behaviour for figures and sections, but not for equations: I get the '\eqref' command for equations.

What is making the function insert '\eqref' instead of '\cref', only for equations?

'reftex-cleveref-cref' is a function in `reftex-ref.el', but I did not find the solution by looking at this file.